# total sum of textfield values of field collection(with unlimited values) in another field out of field collection in same form

Tags: javascript

I am creating a form. it has a field collection. it has a field age in field collection that can be filled unlimited times in single form. I want to add the total of those field values(age) in another single textfield(out of field collection). I don't know how to that as it has same class but always ask for input:ID which is different everytime.

Comment: try this module http://drupal.org/project/computed_field

Comment: thanx for reply. I am trying that too.

Comment: Actually i have written jquery for single field bt nw i want to use those fields as field collection to have multiple inputs in same form. so that query is not working in field collection. any suggestions

Comment: how you are using jQuery? code?

Comment: did u check your code as alert?

Comment: yes..i did... its working properly for just first field ...bt i want 2 make it work for every field of same class sothat it will give me total sum of value entered in those fields

Comment: you can achieve the same using computed field, check this similar question http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/39257/sum-of-integer-vaules-of-a-multi-value-field-using-computed-field-module